# I do not understand the reason for this syntax error

Tags: python

I am a trying to learn python 2 and I do not have any background in computer language
I am using the tutorial "ByeofPython". The exercise ask us to enter this into the editor (text wrangler)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Filename : helloworld.py
print "Hello World'
```

And the save it as helloworld.py. I did this and saved it onto my desktop in a folder called python exercises.

The tutorial then asks us to:

> Run this program by opening a shell (Linux terminal or DOS prompt) and entering the command python
>   helloworld.py. If you are using IDLE, use the menu Edit -> Run Script or the keyboard shortcut
>   Ctrl-F5. The output is as shown below.
>
> ```
> $ python helloworld.py
> Hello World
> ```

However when I go to terminal and enter python helloworld.py I get this

```
python helloworld.py
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong? I feel that I entered everything correctly. I am using a Mac and running python 2.6

Comment: Did you type this in in the python interpreter by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting a SyntaxError because your quotes do not match.

Your print line should be:

```
print "Hello World"
```

not

```
print "Hello World'
```

Comment: Yes, that too, but that's not why the OP get's a SyntaxError... it doesn't match the traceback given. The OP has been typing the command in the python shell or into IDLE..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  It looks like you're right that his first error is typing `python helloworld.py` into the python interpreter.

Comment: The unbalanced quotes give you `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be typing into the python interpreter, and the command you're entering isn't valid Python.
To exit this mode, you could either press CTRL-D (end of file), or CTRL-C (interrupt program).

(I'm not sure if these key sequences are the same on windows)

If you run the command `python` without the name of a script file after it, it will start reading user input as if it was a python program.